# Stolen Stellar Recovery

Tags: xlm, security

I am doing some research, and would like to know:

If had XLM stolen in a hack, is there a way to recover or trace it?

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, yes, you can trace it to the wallet address that it may have been sent to. Recovery, however, is not a guarantee, and rather unlikely. Stellar Development Foundation has an exclusive partnership with Elliptic, the leading provider of crypto-asset risk management solutions for crypto businesses and financial institutions that in some scenarios may be able to help. You can read more about the partnership here: https://www.stellar.org/press-releases/stellar-development-foundation-announces-exclusive-partnership-with-elliptic?locale=en

Your best bet is just to be as safe as possible, and store your XLM yourself. The old adage "not your keys, not your crypto" holds well. Your best bet is to follow the FAQ on protecting your Stellar https://www.stellar.org/community/faq?locale=en#how-do-i-protect-myself-from-scammers